# how to switch focus between different layouts

Tags: android, focus, android-relativelayout

I have three layouts one for showing main menu, second for sub menu, and third for details menu. I have to navigate between these layouts using keyboard arrow buttons. Moving down for main menu to sub menu and from sub menu to details menu works, 
but the problem is when I'm in details menu I cannot go up  sub menu. I tried using the property android:nextFocusUp but it didn't work for me.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#1c1c1c"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pagelogolayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/logoborder">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logoimage"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/listpagelogo"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainmenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pagelogolayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/main_menu_border"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/submenu"
        android:focusable="true">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/submenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainmenu"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/sub_menu_border"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/container" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/submenu"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:nextFocusUp="@+id/submenu"
        />

        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
view.requestFocus();
```

note: your layout has too many nested layout, it will make app's performance is down